# No code is executed after jquery .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

As I stated above, no code would be executed after my .each function. I thought every code would be executed after the each function is ready?!

Heres my js-file:

```
function onUploadLoad() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "headlines_getter.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data1) {
            console.log("debug 2");
            var i = 0;
            var $element = "";
            $.each(data1[i].main, function () {
                console.log("debug 3 ");
                $element += '<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>' + data1[i].main + '</h3>';
                var j = 0;
                $.each(data1[i].sub, function () {
                    console.log("debug 4");
                    $element += '<span><input type="checkbox" name="headlines" data-mini="true" value="blub" /> ' + data1[i].sub[j] + ' </span>';
                    j++;
                });
                $element += '</div>';
                i++;
                var $elements = $($element).appendTo($('#headlinesgroup'));
                $elements.collapsible();
            });
    alert("ok"); // <- this alert is not shown!!
    console.log("debug 12"); // <- also not this console.log!
        }
    });
}
```

If I'm doing an alert before the each-function, everything works fine?!

Thanks in advance.
Best regards, john.

Comment: nothing unexpected. just my debug-numbers, but not debug-number 12! i've changed my question because i put the alert after the ajax, not after the each-function (which is the problem)!

Comment: Your `$.each()` loops are all wrong - you shouldn't be trying to manage your own counter variables and use `$.each()` at the same time. In my answer I've taken a guess at the structure of the JSON returned as the `data1` object in your Ajax success callback, and provided some corresponding code, but obviously I might have guessed wrong so please update your question to show the JSON (and then somebody will give you an answer showing exactly how to process it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line from your code:

```
$.each(data1[i].main, function () {
```

Says to iterate over the properties/elements of `data1[i].main`. That is, given that `i` is 0 at that point, it expects the `.main` property of `data1[0]` to be either an array or an object. Given the way that you then try to keep using `data1[i].main` inside the loop and you are incrementing `i` yourself I suspect that `.main` is not an array or object at all, so neither of your `$.each()` loops are working at all like you think they are.

Just guessing here, but is the structure of your `data1` data actually something like this:

```
[
   { "main" : "some heading 1", "sub" : [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ] },
   { "main" : "some heading 2", "sub" : [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ] },
   { "main" : "some heading 3", "sub" : [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ] }
]
```

That structure corresponds to what you seem to be trying to do inside your `$.each()` loops, but you've gone wrong by trying to use `$.each()` at the same time as separately managing your own `i` and `j` loop counters. You want to use either `$.each()` *or* a traditional `for` loop, but it's like you're trying to do both at once. Assuming the above structure is similar to yours you need to do something like this:

```
    success: function (data1) {
        console.log("debug 2");
        var $element = "";
        $.each(data1, function (i, currentObj) {
            console.log("debug 3 ");
            $element += '<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>' + currentObj.main+ '</h3>';
            $.each(currentObj.sub, function (j, currentSub) {
                console.log("debug 4");
                $element += '<span><input type="checkbox" name="headlines" data-mini="true" value="blub" /> ' +currentSub + ' </span>';
            });
            $element += '</div>';
            var $elements = $($element).appendTo($('#headlinesgroup'));
            $elements.collapsible();
        });
        alert("ok"); 
        console.log("debug 12");
    }
```

Note that nowhere in either `$.each()` loop do I actually make use of the `i` and `j` variables because jQuery is setting `currentObj` equal to `data1[i]` and also it sets `currentSub` equal to `currentObj.sub[j]` (which is also `data1[i].sub[j]`).

Comment: wow, like magic. now everything works fine! thank you very much. seems legit that I don't have to deal with `i` loop counters, as jquery does it for me! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. (You can definitely still _use_ the loop counters inside the loops - though it isn't necessary if you do something similar to what I've shown - but you definitely should not _change_ the loop counters yourself. And make sure they're declared as parameters in the functions, not separately before the `.each()`.)

Comment: i have one question. i've changed my json php file so that now i retrieve data in this form: `[{"main":"Mainheadline1","sub":[{"name":"Subheadline1","sID":"5"},{"name":"Subheadline2","sID":"6"},{"name":"Subheadline3","sID":"8"}]}, ...` . i've changed in the second `.each` function the value from `currentSub` to `currentSub.name`, but it doesn't display the name (it displays nothing). Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: could you please have a look at my last question?

Comment: I would expect it to work if the only thing you've changed is the following line: `$element += '<span><input type="checkbox" name="headlines" data-mini="true" value="blub" /> '  +currentSub.name + ' </span>';` (Don't change the actual `.each()` itself.)

Comment: yeah, i've changed it exactly that way (seems logic to me) but nothing happens. To be more precise, now nothing would be shown from the generated collapsible!

Comment: now it works. i've done an `alert(currentSub.name);` and this confused the system a little bit. i've deleted this line and now it works. so, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

try to add the `error` param to the `$.ajax` request like :

```
function onUploadLoad()
{
    console.log("debug start");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "headlines_getter.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data1) {
            console.log("debug success");
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("debug error");
        }
    });
    console.log("debug end");
}​
```

---

Since the question has changed...

Can you post here the response of your php ? To see if you're manipulating the `data1` the way it has to be manipulated...

Comment: thanks. i've added this snippet, but there's no error in the ajax request. i've changed my question, because i've put the alert after the ajax, not after the each-function (which is the problem)!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the documentation of .each() you can see that the prototype of the callback function needs two parameters

> jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

therefore you could do it like this:

```
$.each(data1[i].main, function (index, element) {

//code inside each

});
```

Comment: jQuery will pass those parameters to the callback function you provide, but they are by no means necessary.